# Swiftからサーバーに画像をアップロードする時に出たエラー

Tags: swift, ios

Swiftからサーバーに画像をアップロードする時に出たエラーの内容がわかりません。
Traceback に

```
objc[31747]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11aa7d998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x119968880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-06-16 23:11:52.837756 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350088] [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
2017-06-16 23:11:54.274757 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_socket_get_input_frames recvmsg(fd 13, 1024 bytes): [54] Connection reset by peer
2017-06-16 23:11:54.276896 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_endpoint_flow_prepare_output_frames [1 127.0.0.1:8000 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Failed to use 1 frames, marking as failed
2017-06-16 23:11:54.277301 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_socket_write_close shutdown(13, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not connected
2017-06-16 23:11:54.277684 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [1 127.0.0.1:8000 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 0 frame count, 0 byte count
2017-06-16 23:11:54.278467 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350154] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled
error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800025cda0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload_save/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload_save/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})
```

と出ました。
これは何のエラーなのでしょうか？
間違いなく存在するURLをSwiftのアップロードの時に指定をしており
localhost8000を他のデバイスからもアクセスできるようにしてサーバーを立ち上げているのですが。

Comment: localhostは実機とシミュレータで意味が変わってくるような気がします。

Comment: ここではシミュレータで試しています。どう変わって来るのでしょうか？

Comment: iOSシミュレータとMacの間は127.0.0.1で同一マシン上ですが、iOS実機で実行すると127.0.0.1はMacではなくなります。(エラーとは関係ない話題ですが)